# Kubectl: the server doesn't have a resource type "cronjobs"

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I ran minikube with:

```
minikube start --vm-driver=kvm2 --kubernetes-version=v1.8.0
```

status:

```
minikube: Running
cluster: Running
kubectl: Correctly Configured: pointing to minikube-vm at 192.168.39.93
```

However, running `kubectl get all` returns this error:

```
error: the server doesn't have a resource type "cronjobs"
```

Anyone have any idea what could be the reason for this?

Comment: What does `kubectl get ns` return?

Comment: What kubectl version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is appearently that there's a bug in Minikube 0.26. Downgrading the Minikube installation is solving it.

Comment: I have restarted the minikube and then finally works for me.